"Window Pane" pattern when training CycleGAN
I've implemented a CycleGAN in Pytorch for style transfer between images. However, I've noticed during training that a distinct "window pane" pattern emerges, regardless of how I tweak different hyperparameters like CNN filter sizes and strides.
Example images (left: early in training, middle: later in training, right: original image):

This pattern is proving difficult to completely remove, so I'm wondering if something about the way the model is set-up might be causing it. Is there something obvious that I can check?
Some additional context:
The encoder portion takes size <3, 256, 256> images and converts them to <512, 1, 1> via Conv2D, BatchNorm2D, ReflectionPad2d, and LeakyRelu layers. The encoded images are then passed through a resnet-style transformation portion (same types of layers), then through a decoder which mirrors the layout of the encoder. Using other encoded sizes, such as <64, 13, 13> makes no difference. Varying the number of layers and their sizes makes no difference either.
Please let me know if more information is required.

I found the problem:
After converting the images to tensors I was using torch.reshape to try swapping the order of <width, height, channels> to <channels, width, height>. However, this didn't work like I had intended and the data was being mutilated.
The proper function is torch.permute, which has solved the issue.
